# Bash not working properly when running Docker as non-root

Tags: python, bash, docker

I want to run a docker with a bash, when i was running with basic configuration it ran as root and it showed the terminal properly. But when i moved to non-root user now the terminal just shows $ and tab is not working, also it does not matter if i move in different folders it just shows the $

I am using a docker-compose.yml file for automatization of the process

here are the two files

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.10

# Create non-root user
RUN groupadd -r dsteam && useradd -r -g dsteam -m dsteam

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /home/dsteam/app/

# Copy and install requirements
COPY ./requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Change directory ownership
RUN chown -R dsteam:dsteam /home/dsteam/app


# Expose the port
EXPOSE 5001

# Switch to non-root user
USER dsteam

# Copy the rest of the application code
COPY . .

# Run your command
# CMD [ "uvicorn", "src.server.app:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80", "--reload" ]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  aiproject:
    build: .
    image: aiproject-image
    container_name: aiproject-container
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    # Override the default command with bash
    command: ["bash"]
```

Comment: Two questions: (1) What does `echo "$TERM"` inside that shell display? (2) What does `echo "<$->"` emit?

Comment: Also, (3) what does `test -t 0 && echo "stdin tty"; test -t 1 && echo "stdout tty"; test -t 2 && echo "stderr tty"` emit?

Comment: (Also, please show the actual command you're using to actually invoke and connect to the container).

Comment: Thanks for your help, the answer of Nick ODell, solved my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But when i moved to non-root user now the terminal just shows $ and tab is not working, also it does not matter if i move in different folders it just shows the $

That sounds like you're using the `/bin/sh` shell. Given that this issue only happens when running as the new user, it's probably getting run because that's the new user's default shell.

When I run your example, and inspect `/etc/passwd`, it looks like the user you've created has `/bin/sh` as their default shell.

```
dsteam:x:999:999::/home/dsteam:/bin/sh
```

I'd suggest passing the `-s` option to useradd to set Bash as your default shell.

Example:

```
RUN groupadd -r dsteam && useradd -r -g dsteam -m -s /bin/bash dsteam
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this solved the issue. I appreciate everybody's help